# 'IS' and 'OR' not recognized when creating SQL View

Tags: sql

I am running a SQL View it has some syntax errors when I use the `OR` and `IS` operators. The code works but I would like to use alternative operators if possible, so I do not get syntax errors.

When I execute the view, a window called **SQL Syntax Errors Encountered** popped up and it says:

> "Error in list of function arguments: 'IS' not recognized. Error in
>   list of function arguments: 'OR' not recognized. SQL text cannot be
>   represented in the grid pane and diagram pane."

Here is the part of the code where the OR and IS operators are used:

```
"...(AADTOver IS NULL) OR AADTOver = 0, AADT, AADTOver))..."
```

The expected result is to not have syntax errors.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to debug this particular issue without seeing the context - would you mind providing the full query? Please also tag the database engine so answers can be reflective of a particular package's conventions.

Comment: Without seeing the full query, it make it hard to determine the problem. However based off the snippet you provided, it appears that you have some issues with Parentheses, as well as comparing values. AADTOver = 0 OR AADT = 0

Comment: I'm going to look more into this IIF ( boolean_expression, true_value, false_value ) since that is what I am trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search with more than one argument, you must use an IN() expression. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (email IS NULL) OR id IN(0, 1, 2)
```